# Get Specific String From RichTextBox

Tags: vb.net, winforms

iam trying to get date and time from internet but i have no idea how to do that, much of code from google not work for me.., then iam trying to get document text from http://www.worldtimeserver.com/current_time_in_ID.aspx to RichTextBox with this code :

```
    Private Function getPageSource(ByVal URL As String) As String
        Dim getWebClient As System.Net.WebClient = New System.Net.WebClient()
        Dim strSource As String = getWebClient.DownloadString(URL)
        getWebClient.Dispose()
        Return strSource
    End Function

RTBDateTime.Text = getPageSource("http://www.worldtimeserver.com/current_time_in_ID.aspx")
```

this block contain date and time for my location :

```
<div class="desc" style="text-align: center">
               <span class="font7">
               4:08 PM 'this line (TIME)
               </span>
               <br>

               <span class="font6">
               Friday, November 28, 2014</span> 'and this line without "</span>" (DATE)
               <br>

               Waktu Indonesia Barat (West Indonesian Time) (WIB) +0700 UTC
               <br>
               <br>

               UTC/GMT is
               09:08
               on
               Friday, November 28, 2014 'or this line for DATE
               <br>
               <br>
  </div>
```

i want to get "4:08 PM" and "Friday, November 28, 2014".. how can i achieve that?

Comment: The best way would be to use HtmlAgilityPack to parse the HTML.

Comment: @Tim i just solve my actual problem using HtmlAgilityPack thanks.., but still your answer does not answer this question.

Comment: It wasn't intended to be a full answer, simply a suggestion, hence why I put it as a comment rather than an answer. :)